# Collision of frames P2

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to determine the points of the players based on the different frame that a bullet hits, is this possible? So basically I want to for example, give 100 points if figurapega matches figura, and 50 points if it does not, but I have not been  please my code below.

```js
///////Here I load the atlas
this.load.atlas('Monsters', 'asset/game1/Monstruos/monstruos.png', 'asset/game1/Monstruos/monstruos.json');

///this is the one I want to use as reference to compare

        createFiguraCompare: function(){
        
                //Figura para comparar
        this.figuritaspega = this.game.add.sprite(800, 140, 'Monsters', this.rnd.integerInRange(0,4));
        this.figuritaspega.scale.set(0.5, 0.5 );
        
        
    },

/////////and this is the one generating sprites that need to be shot at

    
        makeOneFigura: function() {
          
        this.figura = this.game.add.group();
        this.figura.enableBody = true;    
        this.figura.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
    //         for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        this.figura.createMultiple(100, 'Monsters', 0, false);  
    //         }
        this.figura.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
        this.figura.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
        this.figura.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
        this.figura.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true); 


        
        
        
    },
    
      makeFiguras: function(x, y){ 

   if (this.timerFiguras) {
            this.figuras = this.figura.getFirstExists(false);
       if (this.figuras) {
            this.figuras.reset(0, 350);
             this.figuras.frame = this.game.rnd.integerInRange(0,4);  
             this.figuras.body.setCollisionGroup(this.figuraCG);
            this.figuras.body.collides(this.bulletCG); 
            this.figuras.body.velocity.x = 1000;
        }
   };

    },



/////and last but no least the collision handler which is where Im trying to compare but with no luck

    
        collisionBulletFigura: function(bullet, figuras, score, scoreText, figuritaspega) {
        
            if (this.figuras.frame === this.figuritaspega.frame){
       figuras.sprite.kill();
        bullet.sprite.kill();
            this.score += 100;
            this.scoreText.text = this.score;
       }else {
                  figuras.sprite.kill();
        bullet.sprite.kill()
        
         this.score += 50;
            this.scoreText.text = this.score;
       }

            
        
    },
```

Comment: Where is `collisionBulletFigura` fired?
Anyway, I think the problem is that figuras is 'group' and figuritaspega a 'sprite'.

Comment: Hey thanks, ok figuras pega is just 1 ramdomly selected, so does not fires only figuras does, so basically each time you start the level, figuraspega is a single one, and I want to compare to figuras which are several ones, the only ones that fire is figuras here:  this.timerFiguras = this.time.events.loop(500, this.makeFiguras, this); you can think of it like maybe space invaders, if this figura = to figurapega then 100 points, if not you only get 50 kind of thing, I hope I made sense here :)

Comment: For a better explanation think of tanks, but on top 1 sprite comes up, different every time you restart the level, or could be specific no difference there, and basically, mission is to kill5 of those, and when you kill one you get 100 points, there will be other monsters moving, and they will only give 50 points, this is an example.